# Sometime NSManagedobject object become fault when passing object from one controller to another, is there any way to pass object as a value type objC

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data, nsuserdefaults

First controller

```
OptiiMobileTaskDetailViewController *taskDetailVC = (OptiiMobileTaskDetailViewController *)segue.destinationViewController;
[taskDetailVC setTask:task];
```

Second Controller

```
-(void) setTask:(Task *)task {
    _task = task;
}
```

This code working properly but sometime when we use task object in second VC we got Fault object so is there any other way to pass NSManagedobject between view controllers

Comment: Does it matter that you have a fault as long as the fault resolves when you access any properties?

Comment: @Paulw11 here is the issue , when we used that task object property value get nil

Comment: Pass the object's id instead and provide the second controller with its own managed context, so it can instantiate its own image of the database state.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
+(instancetype) taskWithTaskID:(NSNumber *)taskID {
    
    Task *task = [self getManagedObjectForKey:@"taskID" keyValue:taskID];
    if (!task) {
        
        //Create task
        task = [[OptiiMobileDataStore sharedInstance] createNewObjectNamed:NSStringFromClass([self class])];
        task.taskID = taskID;
        [[OptiiMobileDataStore sharedInstance] insertObject:task];
    }
    
    return task; }
```

and get the new copy of data just before it is get default

```
    _task = [Task taskWithTaskID:self.taskID];
```